# Y-Axis positions of barplot and base plot do not match

Tags: r, position, bar-chart, axis

I was trying to plot  a climate diagram and ran into the following problem:
After using barplot(...) for precipitation I superimposed another plot for the temperature. It is necessary for climate diagrams that the two y-axes (mm, °C) align at zero and that the precipitation/temperature ratio is 2:1 (e.g. 20mm precipitation corresponds to 10°C).

The problem: barplot(...) draws the axis to the plot's box while plot(...) leaves some space between the box and the axis margins.

Here is a simplified example. From the grid lines you see that the 0-values do not align:

```
barplot(0:10)
  grid(col=1)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(0:10, xlim=c(-2,14), axes=FALSE)
  axis(4,at=c(0:10), labels=c(0:10))
```

[image]

How can I get the right position and scaling of the two axes?

Comment: In general for complex plots drawings I recommend using ggplot2. However this may be due to the box setting when plotting

Comment: I would prefer not to use ggplot2 for such simple graphs. I also came across the par(...) argument "yaxs" but only tow "styles" are defined for R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `par(new = TRUE)`:

```
barplot(0:10)
grid(col=1)
lines(0:10, type = "p")
axis(4,at = c(0:10), labels = seq(0,20,2))
```

The function `lines()` is the right one here. The argument `type = p` is needed to plot points.
You need to adjust the y-values for the temperature, but now the second y-axis is in the right way, I think.

Comment: this does not work because I need another scaling for the second y-axis (see description)

Comment: ah, ok, so you just changed the axis labels. This means I would have to multiply the temperature by 2... it should work